# SSL/https error when Installing git and configuring github on Beaglebone

Tags: linux, ssl, https, github, beagleboard

I've got a BeagleBone running Angstrom Linux and just finished setting up git and github with the [standard instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-linux)

However, when I try to clone a repository...

```
git clone https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepositoryName
```

...or an individual file...

```
git clone https://github.com/MyUserName/MyRepositoryName/bb.py
```

...I get the following:

```
Cloning into 'bb.py'...
error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) while accessing https
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue on the latest BeagleBone Black with Angstrom Linux, it does not seem to work with https.

Works fine with http, though:

```
git clone http://github.com/...
```

So I just use http to get around the issue for now.